# Compile error with OptionsBuilder for jmh-core version > 1.9

Tags: java, jmh

```
Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(this.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .build();
```

Compilation fine with jmh-core version 1.9, failed with jmh-core version > 1.9

```
Error:java: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse the line: PerformanceBenchmark.benchmark1===,===PerformanceBenchmark_benchmark1.benchmark1===,===Throughput===,===1====,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]===,===[]
```

Java version : 1.8.0_74

Can anyone tell me what went wrong.. ?
Thank you.

```
        <!--Benchmarking framework-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you try to `mvn clean` , then rebuild ?

Comment: Yes I tried. It seems that 1.12 is the last version that jmh-core and jmh-generator-annprocess still work for me

Answer (score 2):

There are two dependencies usually involved: `jmh-core` and `jmh-generator-annprocess`. Their versions should agree. If they don't, then generator may produce the benchmark list in a format that core cannot understand. This most probably is such case.

Comment: I tried to match them both with version 1.15 (newest one for jmh-generator-annprocess). Unluckily, doesn't work

Comment: Provide the MCVE, please.

Comment: Updated with pom as you requested

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a MCVE, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- please provide a sample buildable project where it fails. Showing only the part of your build file is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `jmh-core` and `jmh-generator-annprocess` versions matched, but the build still failed. It happened after JMH version was increased. I resolved it by cleaning and rebuilding the project in IntelliJ.